# SonarQube: Issues for one project are not displayed

Tags: sonarqube

In my SonarQube installation for one project the issues overview can't be displayed, it always shows "Still working..." at the top.

See http://didge.my-wan.de/sonar/component_issues/index?id=net.troja.eve%3Aproducersaid

When I navigate to the files directly I can see all the issues! Only the overview doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

PS: I change to logging to debug, but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a string escaping bug. If you rename your project to remove the quote character, the page will display correctly. I have created a [JIRA issue to track this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6549), will be fixed in 5.2 (and maybe backported to 5.1.x).